# OpenGL ES 2.0: Alpha blending issues

Tags: opengl-es, xamarin.ios, glsl

I trying to blend my gui komponents again the background but atm it looks very strange, even when i set the alpha to 1.0 in the shader the blendings are really strange.

I enable the blending with the following code:

```
GL.Enable(All.Blend);
GL.BlendFunc(All.SrcAlpha, All.One);
```

With alpha set to 1.0 the buttons look like this ( Note: One button is missing ):
[image: Buttons]

The pixel shader is simple:

```
varying lowp vec2 textureCoordinates;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(texture, textureCoordinates).bgr, 1.0); // r and b switched, because the colors are switched????
}
```

One of the buttons:
[image]

Comment: Why do you switch the colors in the shader anyway?

Comment: Can you show the original image of the buttons?

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you could provide a self-contained test case, either hosted somewhere (e.g. github) or a zip file attached to a bug report (e.g. http://bugzilla.xamarin.com). Right now it's hard to say where the issue could be - and not easy to replicate something similar.

Comment: @ChristianRau Thats a good question, the texture format is RGBA. I don't know why this happens.
Button image attached. I'm wondering how this could happen. Why does the device ignores the alpha transparency completly?

Comment: You won't belive me, its the blending mode. Changing it to OneMinusSrcAlpha makes everything work.

Comment: I even can propose, these artifacts are caused by premultiplied alpha in texture (very IMHO)

Comment: @FelixK. How is "the texture format is RGBA" an answer to "why do you switch the color components?"? Keep in mind that OpenGL is completely free to store the RGBA components in whatever order it likes internally and always gives you red when you request red. If it is because you have to initialize the texture from a BGR image, then can't you just specify GL_BGR as image format (not as internal format, of course) in `glTexImage2D`?

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes i could use BRGA, but i think its a problem with the DDS loader, because the dds image format is RGBA, maybe i have to swap the R and B channel after loading.

Comment: @FelixK. if you answered your own answer (as your comment suggest about `OneMinusSrcAlpha` then please use the "Your Answer" to fill it and then mark is as answered (it's alright to answer your own questions). That way all SO users searching for a similar question will know there's an answer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OneMinusSrcAlpha` instead of `One` solves the problem.